# Is it possible to share/inherit className for all TableCell's of a TableRow?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have something like this:

```js
<TableRow>
  <TableCell className={clsx(disabled && classes.disabled)}> ...
  <TableCell className={clsx(disabled && classes.disabled)}> ...
  <TableCell className={clsx(disabled && classes.disabled)}> ...
...
</TableRow>
```

In other words, I repeat myself for each `TableCell`. Is it possible to do this differently and avoid the repetition? Somehow inherit the class name from above or share it?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, this would be solved by using a CSS selector for table cells inside the disabled table row or the disabled table.

In your CSS file, you have something like this:

```css
tr.disabled td {/* some disabled styles */}
```

And then in the component, you use the class on the row and not the cell:

```
<TableRow className={clsx(disabled && classes.disabled)}>
  <TableCell> ...
</TableRow>
```

That said, usually you would not repeat yourself in react all that much even if you were to use the styles like in your question. Because a lot of times, you can get away by using map in some way.

```
<TableRow>
  {Object.entries(row).map(([key, val]) => <TableCell className={clsx(disabled && classes.disabled)}></TableCell>)
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. For your last point, other components are used to render the cell content for each object field so using a map is an interesting trick that I can't really throw in here.